# For the substitution rule 0->10, 1->100 Show that $B_n$ = $2B_{n−1} + B_{n−2}.\,(n ≥ 3)$ with $B_1 = 1, B_2 = 2.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Starting with the digit 0, make a string of symbols by the substitution rule
$$0 → 10,  1 → 100$$
(a) Write down the first four strings (including the initial string $0$) which results from the application of the substitution rule.

(b) Let an and $A_n$ denote the number of digits $0$ or $1$ in the string after $n$ applications of the substitution rule (the initial string $0$ is for $n = 1$). Let $B_n$ denote the total number of digits in the $n’th$ string. Show that

$B_n = 2B_{n-1} + B_{n−2}$, for $(n ≥ 3)$ with $B_1 = 1, B_2 = 2.$

For part (a) I have

$n = 1$, string is $0$

$n = 2$, string is $10$

$n = 3$, string is $10010$

$n = 4$, string is $100101010010$

From these 4 strings it is clear that the recurrence is correct but I don't know how to go about constructing it.

I was thinking every string $B_n$, will have the string $B_{n-1}$ at the head and the tail and the string $B_{n-2}$ in between. But I don't really know where to go from here. Any help/tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $0$'s, $A_n$ be the number of $1$'s,
$B_n$ be the total at the $n$'th round.  Then

(1)
$$
B_n = a_n + A_n.
$$

Since each $0$ generates a $0$, each $1$ two $0$'s for the next round, we get

(2)
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + 2\, A_n,
$$

Similarly, each $0$ generates a $1$, and each $1$ generates a $1$, we get

(3)
$$
A_{n+1} = a_n + A_n = B_n,
$$
where we used (1) in the last step.

Shift $n$ by one, we get

(4)
$$
A_n = B_{n-1}
$$

Adding (2) and (3), we get

(5)
$$
B_{n+1} = 2 \, B_n + A_n
= 2\, B_n +B_{n-1}.
$$
where we have used (4) in the last step.

By the way, $B_n$'s are the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and the solution of (5) is
$$
B_n =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\left[
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}
-
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}
\right].
$$